# CanvasJs multiple charts created but only one chart is rendered

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I want to dynamically create a CanvasJS chart depending on N amount of objects from a JSON array. If a JSON array has 3 objects, the web page should be able to display 3 charts.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="spectraContainers">
 </div>
```

Through the id "spectraContainers", I have a javascript function that dynamically creates a new div with a unique id. In that same function, a new chart is created with its unique id.

```
document.getElementById("chartContainers").innerHTML += '<div class="row"> <div id="chart_container_' + chartNumber + '" style="width: 100 %; height: 500px; ">Container </div></div>';

...
...
...

var chartContainerID = "chartcontainer_" + chartNumber;
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(chartContainerID, {
            animationEnabled: true,
            zoomEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2", 
            title: {
                text: chartTitle,
            },
            axisX: {
                title: "x axis label",
                gridDashType: "dash",
                gridThickness: 2
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "y axis label",
                gridDashType: "dash",
                gridThickness: 2
            },
            dataPointMaxWidth: 20,
            dataPointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: points
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
```

I've verified that all values are valid. It seems like only ONE canvasJS chart (the third object from the json array) can be rendered in a page within this function. If I were to specifically generate a chart for index 0 or 1 in the json array, the specified index for the chart will be rendered.

I know it's possible to render multiple canvasJs charts by manually creating a new chart variable for each uniqueID. However, I would like to dynamically generate N-amount of charts. I am pretty new to javascript and would appreciate any advice!!

Comment: is chartNumber a string or integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using innerHTML replaces the contents of div element rather than appending child element. Try using append method.

Comment: Perhaps this could be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Through inspecting elements in the browser, I can see the div blocks with a unique ID is being created. The problem seems to be the variable "chart" is being overwritten? Stepping through the code, I can see that it creates chart 1, deletes it, and then creates chart 2...

Comment: Actually, you were correct. I've created a new element using document.createElement('div'), set the uniqueID, set the CSS, and then called the appendChild() you mentioned. It was able to successfully display all charts!